# Dataframe to Snowflake -> error with the library snowflake connector (AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get')

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to uplaod a dataframe to snowflake, however I get an Attribute error when I'm uploading it.

My dataframe:

|  | Type | VALUE | MATRICULE | CATEGORIE | LINE | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | 100 | 1 | Base | 3 | 2023-11-01 |
| 1 | B | Nan | 1 | Base | 4 | 2023-11-01 |
| 2 | C | Nan | 1 | Base | 5 | 2023-11-01 |
| 3 | D | Nan | 1 | Base | 6 | 2023-11-01 |
| 4 | E | Nan | 1 | Base | 7 | 2023-11-01 |

My code:

```
from snowflake.connector.pandas_tools import pd_writer
from conn_snowflake import engine
from transform import df

 
if_exists = 'replace'
schema='SHCEMA_NAME'
table_name='TABLE_NAME'


res_sql=final_df.to_sql(
                table_name.lower()
                , engine
                , if_exists=if_exists
                , index=False
                , method=pd_writer
                , schema=schema
                )
print('Table '+table_name+' upload to snowlfake on schema '+schema)
```

How I create the engine:

```
engine = create_engine('snowflake://{user}:{password}@{account_identifier}/{database_name}/{schema_name}?warehouse={warehouse_name}&role={role_name}'.format(
            user='USER_NAME',
            password=os.environ['SNOWFLAKE_PASSWORD'] ,
            account_identifier='**********.**-***-*',
            database_name='DATABASE_NAME',
            schema_name='SCHEMA_NAME',
            warehouse_name='WH',
            role_name='ADMIN'
        )
)
```

My error:

```
File "..../.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/connector/auth/_auth.py", line 285, in authenticate
    if ret["data"].get("nextAction") in (
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

What am I doing wrong ? Or should I change my method (because my dataframe has 200 000 rows)?